# Reduce the size of a numpy array by splitting it and summing between the splits

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

I want to split it and sum the sub-arrays to get a smaller array.

For example, i want to split it given the following group sizes: `[[2, 1], [1, 3]]`

```
1 | 2 3 4
2 | 3 4 5
---------
3 | 4 5 6
```

The result should be:

```
1+2  2+3+4+3+4+5
3    4+5+6


3 21
3 15
```

Is there an efficient way to do this with numpy functions instead of for loops? I need to do it on high dimensional arrays. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to always split it in 4 parts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a bigger array:

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 8))
print(arr)
[[3 5 1 9 7 3 0 1]
 [7 8 3 7 7 8 8 4]
 [3 0 2 2 2 5 4 9]
 [3 5 8 5 7 8 3 8]
 [3 2 7 0 9 4 0 8]
 [9 9 4 1 8 9 4 2]]
```

Then you can call [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) two times on different axis:

```
def add_blocks(arr, s1, s2):
    s1, s2 = [0] + s1[:-1], [0] + s2[:-1]
    arr1 = np.add.reduceat(arr, np.cumsum(s1), axis=0)
    arr2 = np.add.reduceat(arr1, np.cumsum(s2), axis=1)
    return arr2

add_blocks(arr, [2, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 5])
array([[10, 13,  4, 54],
       [ 9,  7, 17, 74],
       [ 9,  9,  4, 24]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Didn't know `np.add.*`. That's perfect thanks!